# Angular search $watch delay

Tags: angularjs

On this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyfFnJ9A2R1qCxhL22LN?p=preview) when I search it doesnt get the total of age but instead it will get the total of age previous searched.

**script**

```
  $scope.$watch('search',function(){
    console.log($scope.filteredItems);
    if($scope.filteredItems){
            var x = $scope.filteredItems.length;
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
                total = total + parseInt($scope.filteredItems[i].age);
            }
            $scope.getTotal = total;
        }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<tr dir-paginate="data in (filteredItems = (names | filter:search | orderBy:orderByColumn:!reverseSort | itemsPerPage:5))">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

I think `$watch` is not a good choice is their anyway alternative than `$watch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$watch`, a simple `getTotal()` function is enough.

So Just change your `getTotal` property into function and remove `$watch`.

Do it like, In **HTML** :

```
 <div>total age <b>{{getTotal()}}</b></div>
```

In **Controller**:

```
$scope.getTotal = function() {
   var total = 0;
   if ($scope.filteredItems) {
     var x = $scope.filteredItems.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      total = total + parseInt($scope.filteredItems[i].age);
     }
   }
    return total;
  }
```

Here is [Fixed **plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NNR24uCw0Uo9Y9XINoOQ?p=preview)

EDIT

$watch doesn't work in correct way because $watch takes precedence over filter, and it runs before your data is filtered, So you always have previous data.

Comment: I think this doesnt work if the `$scope.names` was came from ajax

Comment: It will work, as soon as you have `$scope.names` bind to HTML, there is no relation to the source of `names` array.

Comment: so why $watch was delay sir? and dont total the age right away?

Comment: glad to help you, :), and I think it doesn't work in correct way because `$watch` takes precedence over `filter`, and it runs before your data is filtered, So you always have previous data.